# how adding spinner on the toolbar below the toolbar title?

Tags: android, spinner, toolbar, samsung-mobile

I everybody,

I'm developping an android app and i'd like to add spinners (contains in layout) on the toolbar, below the toolbar title like samsung do with "Call log" menu :

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1pGazzf7cP4bE4zQllrNzFLdVU/view?usp=sharing

Samsung add 3 horizontal tab below the toolbar title "Journal".

So my app look like this :

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1pGazzf7cP4cWpPd0Y5MlBhTFU/view?usp=sharing

I'd like to add my layout (pink rectangle) on my yellow toolbar, with the intention of using hiding toolbar scrolling in futur.

Toolbar and layout xml :

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:popupTheme="@style/AppThemeAccueilToolbar"
    android:theme="@style/AppThemeAccueilToolbar"
    android:id="@+id/toolbarAccueil"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:elevation="@dimen/toolbarElevation"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/appBarTopMargin"
    >

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/spinnerLayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="99"
    android:layout_below="@+id/toolbarAccueil">

    <Spinner
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/accueilAnneeSpinner"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="33"
        />

    <Spinner
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/accueilSpinner"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="33"
        />

    <Spinner
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/accueilMatiereSpinner"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="33"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: So your question is: How can I add my layout to the toolbar to achieve hiding the toolbar while scrolling?

Comment: Yes it is, just below the toolbar title, sorry if I am not clear. . Do you have any idea ?

Comment: no, sorry I`d just tried to help other people to understand, what you actually want, so yout get a faster and better answer :)